# Can't access template ref property when route changes vue3/nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

```
<template>
<div ref="sample"></div>
<template>

<script setup>
const sample = ref()
onMounted(()=>{

console.log(sample.value.offsetWidth)
// output on first page render: 300
//render when the route is changed: 0

})
</script>
```

`nextTick, watcheffect` ...
I tried of them. none of them change the result.

I can only access ref properties using `settimeout` in `onMounted`.

```
onMounted(()=>{
 

    setTimeout(() => {
   
    console.log(sample.value.offsetWidth)
    // output on first page render: 300
    //render when the route is changed: 300
        
    }, 300);
})
```

Doesn't on mounted already show that the dom is fully ready?

Comment: What do you mean by then the route is changed? If you use keep-alive, obMounted will only be called once, you might try to add an `onActivated` hook. https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onactivated

Comment: no I don't use `keepalive`. My purpose in changing the route is this; go to the relevant page from another page.
`onMounted` works every time. just Cannot access template ref properties when coming from another page.